# Can't get menu, countdown, or score counter to display in Java

Tags: java, swing, menu, frame, countdown

I am currently working on a simple basketball game in java. I have four classes in total, Main, Countdown, Menu, and MenuPanel. The countdown is a separate frame that I am trying to add to my main frame. And Menu is a menu for the game that I am trying to display, but every time I do, its just a blank white frame. I cant get these to work. Countdown wont display and Menu is just blank. Here are the classes I am using:

Main:
    package finalproject;

```
import basicgraphics.BasicFrame;
import basicgraphics.CollisionEventType;
import basicgraphics.Sprite;
import basicgraphics.SpriteCollisionEvent;
import basicgraphics.SpriteComponent;
import basicgraphics.images.Picture;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JLabel;



class Rim extends Sprite {
Picture basePic;
Rim() throws IOException {
    basePic = new Picture("rim.jpg");
    setPicture(basePic);
}}

class Backboard extends Sprite {
Picture basePic;
Backboard() throws IOException {
    basePic = new Picture("backboard.jpg");
    setPicture(basePic);
}

public void processEvent(SpriteCollisionEvent ce) {
            if (ce.eventType == CollisionEventType.SPRITE) {
                if (ce.xlo) {
                    setVelX(Math.abs(getVelX()));
                }
                if (ce.xhi) {
                    setVelX(-Math.abs(getVelX()));
                }
                if (ce.ylo) {
                    setVelY(Math.abs(getVelY()));
                }
                if (ce.yhi) {
                    setVelY(-Math.abs(getVelY()));
                }

}}}

class Background extends Sprite{
  Picture basePic;
  Background() throws IOException{
    basePic = new Picture("background.jpg");
    setPicture(new Picture("background.jpg"));
}}

class BasketBall extends Sprite {
  Picture basePic;
  BasketBall() throws IOException {
    basePic = new Picture("basketball2.png");
    setPicture(basePic);
}

public void preMove() {

 this.setVelY(this.getVelY() + 0.03);
}

//public int score = 0;

//public void processEvent(SpriteCollisionEvent se) {
    //if(se.sprite2 instanceof Rim) {
       // int score;
       // System.out.println("score");
    //}}
 JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: 0");
 public void scored(){
 //scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
 }

@Override
public void processEvent(SpriteCollisionEvent ce) {
            if (ce.eventType == CollisionEventType.WALL) {
                if (ce.xlo) {
                    setVelX(Math.abs(getVelX()));
                }
                if (ce.xhi) {
                    setVelX(-Math.abs(getVelX()));
                }
                if (ce.ylo) {
                    setVelY(Math.abs(getVelY()));
                }
                if (ce.yhi) {
                    setVelY(-Math.abs(getVelY()));
                }

}}}

public class Main {

  public static enum STATE{
  MENU, 
  GAME;
};

public static STATE State = STATE.MENU;

public static Countdown countdown;
//public static Menu menu;
//public static MenuPanel menupanel;

//int score = 0;


//JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: 0");


public void scored()
{

//scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
//scoreLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 50, 50);

}


 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     countdown = new Countdown();
   //menu = new Menu("Basketball", "Background.jpg");

    BasicFrame bball = new BasicFrame("BasketBall");
    SpriteComponent sc = new SpriteComponent();

    final BasketBall ball = new BasketBall();
    ball.setX(350);
    ball.setY(280);

    //final Countdown countdown = new Countdown();
    //countdown.setX(350);
    //countdown.setY(280);

    Background court = new Background();
    court.setX(0);
    court.setY(0);

    Rim rim = new Rim();
    rim.setX(163);
    rim.setY(186);

    Backboard backboard = new Backboard();
    backboard.setX(159);
    backboard.setY(140);

    bball.add("BasketBall",sc,0,0,1,1);
    //menu.add("Menu",sc, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    sc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(575,400));

    sc.addSprite(court);
    //sc.addSprite(countdown);
    sc.addSprite(rim);
    sc.addSprite(backboard);
    sc.addSprite(ball);


    bball.show();

    //if(State == STATE.GAME){
    sc.start(0,5);
    //}
    //else if (State == STATE.MENU){ 
    menu.show();

    //}


        bball.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
            //if (State == STATE.GAME){
            if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            {
                ball.setVelX(ball.getVelX() + -0.2);

            } 
            else if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            {
                ball.setVelX(ball.getVelX() +0.2);

            } 
            else if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
                ball.setVelY(ball.getVelY() - 1.0);

            }

            }});
}}
```

Countdown:
    package finalproject;

```
import basicgraphics.Sprite;
import basicgraphics.images.Picture;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Countdown extends Sprite{

    Timer timer;
    int counter = 10;


    /*Picture basePic;
    Countdown() throws IOException {
    if (counter == 1);

    basePic = new Picture("one.png");

    if (counter == 2);

        basePic = new Picture("two.png");

}*/


public void Countdown() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("timer");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    final JLabel label = new JLabel("10");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    //panel.add(frame);


    timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            counter--;
            if (counter == -1) {
                timer.removeActionListener(this);
                  timer.stop();
            }

        }
    });
    timer.start();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Countdown();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Menu:
    package finalproject;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Menu extends JFrame


{   
private Image background;
private MenuPanel mp;
private ActionListener al;
private Box b;
private final String MENU[] = {"New Game", "Continue", "High Scores", 
"Exit"};

public Menu(String name, String imagename)
{
    super(name);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    try
    {

UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    mp = new MenuPanel(imagename);
    mp.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 600);
    getContentPane().add(mp);
    setSize(700, 600);
}
public Menu(String name, ActionListener al)
{
    super(name);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    try
    {

UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
    mp = new MenuPanel();
    mp.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 600);
    getContentPane().add(mp);
    for(int i = 0; i < MENU.length; i++)
    {
        JButton jb = new JButton(MENU[i]);
        this.add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(al);
        jb.setBounds(250, 400 + 32 * i, 200, 30);
        mp.add(jb);
    }
    setSize(700, 600);
    setVisible(true);
}
public Menu(String name)
{
    super(name);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    try
    {

UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp = new MenuPanel();
    mp.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 600);
    getContentPane().add(mp);
    setSize(700, 600);
}
public void setActionListener(ActionListener al)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MENU.length; i++)
    {
        JButton jb = new JButton(MENU[i]);
        this.add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(al);
        jb.setBounds(250, 400 + 32 * i, 200, 30);
        mp.add(jb);
    }
    setVisible(true);
}
public Menu(String name, String imagename, ActionListener al)
{
    super(name);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    try
    {

UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp = new MenuPanel(imagename);
    mp.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 600);
    getContentPane().add(mp);
    for(int i = 0; i < MENU.length; i++)
    {
        JButton jb = new JButton(MENU[i]);
        this.add(jb);
        jb.addActionListener(al);
        jb.setBounds(250, 400 + 32 * i, 200, 30);
        mp.add(jb);
    }
    setSize(700, 600);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

MenuPanel: 
    package finalproject;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuPanel extends JPanel
{
private String imgName;
public MenuPanel()
{
    super();
    setLayout(null);
    imgName = "";
    setSize(700, 600);
    setVisible(true);
}
public MenuPanel(String image)
{
    super();
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(700, 600);
    imgName = image;
    setVisible(true);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    if(!imgName.equals(""))
    {
        try 
        {
            MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker (this);
            Image intro = 
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imgName);
            mt.addImage(intro, 0);
            mt.waitForID(0);
            g.drawImage(intro, 0, 0, this);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sorry I am new at this. Any help would be appreciated. I really need help. Thanks.

Comment: This sounds very much like an issue where you are doing a long running (possibly never returning) operation on the UI Thread, which is preventing your UI from being painted. Looking through your code, this line: 'mt.waitForID(0);' looks like a candidate. In any case, you shouldn't be doing Image loading in your paintComponent method. Do that first, before you component is visualized

Comment: How would I go about fixing that? @ControlAltDel

Comment: @dale [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)